# creating a new dataset from large datset xarray

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have a large dataset, with hourly data for an entire year. What I want to do is to create a new dataset with specific variables at sepcific distances from a point source and use all the data to create a box and wiskers plot.

The dataset has time, lon and lat and a concentration variable with multiple dimensions:
Concentration[hours,lat, lon]

I want to create a dataset that loops through all of the times for different lat and lon and produce a concentration output for all time at each of these different locations, to then use it to create a box and wisker plot and to show the decreace of atmospheric concetration from a point source. I know the specific grids I am interested in but need help setting up the script.

EDIT:

I cropped the Global dataset and this is what the output currently looks like:
time: (8761), latitude: (30), longitude: (30)

I tried using a for loop, but it would not allow me to loop over lat/lon...

```
for i in range(8761):
   print(Conc[i,:,:])
```

This lets me loop over all times and see the conc at all grids, but I want to instead of printing create a new ds, and also only loop through certains grids..

I wants a list that provides me 8761 concentrations values for each grid that I specify, and to keep all the data in one dataset so I can make a Box plot from this...

Comment: could you show us a small example of how your data looks like and the code of what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have added some details, let me know if this clarifies anything..

Comment: This should help with the reshape/extract part. Essentially - don't use a loop. Instead, select all the data for the relevant points using DataArray indexers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70879766/fast-efficient-way-to-extract-data-from-multiple-large-netcdf-files/70883692#70883692